# Excel VBA: Type mismatch while opening workbook?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I don't it sounds stupid but it was working before.  And I don't know why it suddenly stopped working.  I tried to exit **Excel** and re-run the code.  Same problem regardless what **workbook** I tried to open.  The code is as below:

```
Sub Check()

Dim myFile As Variant
Dim wb As Workbooks

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please Choose the Info File")

If myFile = False Then
    End
End If

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFile) '<-- Getting "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

End Sub
```

Comment: simple variable declaration error. see answer. I doubt it just stopped working - probably a copy/paste error???

Answer (score 3):

Variable defined incorrectly

Change

```
Dim wb As Workbooks
```

To singular

```
Dim wb As Workbook
```

Comment: I was actually surprised that VBE allows to `Dim` anything as `Workbooks`. `VarType(wb)` returns 9 -> Object in both cases. I see that it can be done with collection of any specific objects.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk `Workbooks` is a class. How surprising is it that you can put that type in a `Dim` statement's `As` clause?